# Spring WebClient POST request doesnt seem to work when passing Domain objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

Having an issue where the WebClient Call fails when passing a domain object but passing as a JSON String works :

This works :

```java
String req="{\n" +
            "\"Login\": \"1121\",\n" +
            "\"Password\": \"1212=121\",\n" +
            "\"Domain\": \"corpdev.net\"\n" +
            "}";
```

```java
String respo=webClient.post()
                .uri("https://sssss.com")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(req)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .block();
```

but the same using a Domain object doesnt work :

```java
String resp = webClient
                .post()
                .uri("https://sssss.com")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
                .body(Mono.just(login),Login.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
```

```java
public class Login {
    private String Login;
    private String Password;
    private String Domain;
}
```

I am a bit new to Webflux and cant seem to get this working . Seems like iam missing something simple . I was expecting the second option to work as it seems straight forward but they object value doesnt seem to be sent to the Rest call .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebClient` uses `Jackson` library to encode the content payload. Encoding is delegated from `WebClient` to `Jackson` via `Jackson2JsonEncoder`. `Jackson2JsonEncoder` uses `ObjectMapper` (a component which acts as a high level API to the `Jackson` library) to serialize your class to a textual JSON representation.

And the problem is, your `Login` class is not serializable to JSON in its current form.
You can do one of the following:

1. generate getters on your class such as `getLogin()`, `getPassword()` etc.
2. if you are on recent Java, you can change `Login` from `class` to `record`
3. instead of generating getters, you can annotate the fields with `@JsonProperty` annotation

Any of the three points above acts as hint to `Jackson` (the library doing the actual encoding) how to serialize your class to JSON.

Also, it is a convention in Java to start class field names in lower case.

So assuming your `Login` is now a `record`, you can use it with `WebClient` like so

```
String respo = webClient.post()
                .uri("https://sssss.com")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(new Login("Login","Password","Domain")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
```

Comment: Thank you .Much appreciated . These options work fine and work as expected .

Comment: I didn't notice the getter / setter issue because get used with lombok. Good catch

Answer (score 0):

I've just compared with my current project and the only difference I can see is based on the way you passed the request body, can you try to replace the line :

```
.body(Mono.just(login),Login.class)
```

by

```
.bodyValue(login)
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks  alot . I have tried this bodyValue option also and it doesnt work . Basically it doesnt pass the Login object as in the reponse i get the empty error message . I have tried several options .